# Implement added, changed and removed server side

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications

**Context :** I am using a Collection `Params` to call method from the Server to a C app. The C app does its stuff and then calls the server by RPC to send me the results. With the result, I get the `Params ID` to delete the corresponding element.
With the deletion of the Element of `Params`, the C app gets a `removed` message. I want to prevent this behavior to avoid overloading the C app of messages.

I've thinked about implementing the `removed` event into the Publish method on the server to prevent the server from informing the C app. I just want the C app to be inform about `added` events.

On the Meteor Doc, there is an example of implementation of `added` and `removed` but I don't understand it. Can someone help me ?

I've tried this (don't work at all) :

```
Meteor.publish('expert_mode_parameters', function ()
{
  var self = this;

  var handle = Expert_Mode_Parameters.find().observeChanges({
    added: function ()
    {
        return Expert_Mode_Parameters.find();
    },
    removed: function ()
    {
        return [];
    }
  });

  self.ready();

  self.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by C app? is it application written in C language ?

Comment: Yep, and the app communicates with the Meteor Server with websocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your goal is to subscribe to a data set but only receive `added` messages, not `changed` or `removed`.

The below code should do this:

```
Meteor.publish('expert_mode_parameters', function () {
  var self = this;

  var handle = Expert_Mode_Parameters.find().observe({
    added: function (document) {
      self.added("expert_mode_parameters", document._id, document);
    }
  });

  self.ready();

  self.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
  });
}
```

The concept is, you're watching the results of `Expert_Mode_Parameters.find()` and then calling `self.added(document)` when there is a new item. The same thing can easily be expanded to include `changed`.

Comment: Hum... I was close. Thank you very much !

Comment: Doing this, the DDP message's is not formated the same way as in "normal" publication. The `id` field is empty, the data are in `collection` instead of `fields` which is absent of the message. Is it a normal behavior or i'm doing things wrong ?

Comment: Just modified my answer. The added function actually takes three arguments: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_added